# IF statement with multiple expressions

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to construct IF statement with multiple conditions but I can't get echo 'TRUE' with this PHP code.

```
<?php
$totalDays = 4;
$startDateL = 'Friday';
$endDateL = 'Monday';
$pickupTime = '12:00:00';
$returnTime = '9:00:00';

if($totalDays == 4 AND 
$pickupTime == '12:00:00' AND 
$returnTime == '09:00:00' AND 
$startDateL == 'Friday' AND 
$endDateL == 'Monday') {
   echo 'TRUE';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$returnTime` is '9:00:00', but you compare it against '09:00:00' in your condition.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that typo. Everything is working now!

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo, see the comment.

```
$totalDays  = 4;
$pickupTime = '12:00:00';
$returnTime = '09:00:00'; // I cnanged this time
$startDateL = 'Friday';
$endDateL   = 'Monday';

if (($totalDays  == 4) AND
    ($pickupTime == '12:00:00') AND
    ($returnTime == '09:00:00') AND
    ($startDateL == 'Friday') AND
    ($endDateL   == 'Monday'))
{
  echo 'TRUE';
}
else echo 'FALSE';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        $totalDays  = 4;
        $startDateL = 'Friday';
        $endDateL   = 'Monday';
        $pickupTime = '12:00:00';
        $returnTime = '09:00:00'; //<== MAKE SURE THE FORMATS ARE THE SAME '09:00:00' NOT '9:00:00'

        if($totalDays == 4 AND
            $pickupTime == '12:00:00' AND
            $returnTime == '09:00:00' AND
            $startDateL == 'Friday' AND
            $endDateL   == 'Monday') {
                echo 'TRUE';
        }
```